# Questions about Understanding The First Part of Billingsley's Proof of Strong Markov Property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

I'm reading about the strong markov property in Billingsley. I'm confused about some aspects of the proof:

> Theorem (Strong Markov Property): Let $\tau$ be a stopping time and
>   $$B^*_t(\omega) = B_{\tau(\omega)+t}(\omega) - B_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$$
>   Then $(B^*_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion and independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ which is to say:
>   $$\textbf{P}(\{B^*_{t_1},...,B^{*}_{t_k}\} \in A \cap M) = \textbf{P}(\{B^{*}_{t_1},...,B^{*}_{t_k}\} \in A) \textbf{P}(M) = \textbf{P}(\{B_{t_1},...,B_{t_k}\} \in A) \textbf{P}(M)$$
>   for any $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and for any $M \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$
>
> *Proof*: Supposed first that $\tau$ has countable range $V$ and let $t_0$ be some point in $V$. Since
>   $$\{\omega:B^*_t(\omega)\in A\} = \bigcup_{t_o\in V}\{\omega:B_{t_0+t}(\omega)-B_{t_0}(\omega),\tau(\omega)=t_o\}$$
>   $B^*_t$ **is a random variable.**  Also if $M \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ and $i$ is a finite index:
>   $$ \bigg( \bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\} \bigg) \cap M = \bigcup_{t_o\in V}\{\bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\},\tau(\omega)=t_o,M\}$$
>   so that
>   $$\textbf{P}(\bigg( \bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\} \bigg) \cap M) = \sum_{t_o\in V}\textbf{P}(\{\bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\},\tau(\omega)=t_o,M\})$$
>   If $M \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$, then $M \cap \{\tau = t_0\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t_0}$. Further, if $\tau = t_0$, then $B^*_t$ is just a translated Brownian motion so that we can use the usual markov property:
>   $$\sum_{t_o\in V}\textbf{P}(\{\bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\},\tau(\omega)=t_o,M\}) \\ = \sum_{t_o\in V}\textbf{P}(\{\bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\})\textbf{P}(\tau(\omega)=t_o,M\}) \quad (*) \\ = \textbf{P}(\{\bigcup_{i}\{\omega:B^*_{t_i}(\omega)\in A_i\}) \textbf{P}(M) \quad (**)$$
>   **This proves the first and third equality, to get the second, consider the case $M = \Omega$.**

Then there's some work on moving to the continuous case which I haven't gotten to yet. My questions:

1. Why is the first bolded statement showing that $B^*_t$ is a random variable? Is it showing that $B^*_t$ is measurable for any $\tau$?
2. In equation $(*)$, I thought the $t_i$ were fixed, do they vary so they're always "ahead" of $t_0$? If the $t_i$ are fixed, how does one invoke markov property for $t_0$ sufficiently large?
3. This is related to the last question -- for equation $(**)$, for the sum to push through to $\textbf{P}(\tau(\omega)=t_o,M\})$, the $t_i$'s would have to be constant right?
4. I don't understand the final bolded statement. The three equalities that they wish to show must be equivalent for any $M\ \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$. How is it sufficient to choose one case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $B_t^*$ is a random variable because for any Borel set $A$, $\{B^*_t\in A\}$ is a *countable* union of measurable sets:

$$
\bigcup_{t_0\in V}\{(B_{t_0+t}-B_{t_0})\in A,\tau=t_0\}.
$$

2. The indices $\{t_i\}$ are fixed but their "independent" of the index set of the original process and you care about $B_{t_i}'=B_{t_i+t_0}-B_{t_0}$.
3. The second line (*) is wrong. The whole argument is as follows:
   \begin{align}
   &\mathsf{P}(\{(B_{t_1}^{*},\ldots,B_{t_k}^{*})\in A\}\cap M) \\
   &\qquad=\sum_{t_0\in V}\mathsf{P}(\{(B_{t_1}^{*},\ldots,B_{t_k}^{*})\in A\}\cap M\cap\{\tau=t_0\}) \\
   &\qquad=\sum_{t_0\in V}\mathsf{P}(\{(B_{t_1}',\ldots,B_{t_k}')\in A\}\cap M\cap\{\tau=t_0\}) \\
   &\qquad=\sum_{t_0\in V}\mathsf{P}((B_{t_1}',\ldots,B_{t_k}')\in A)\mathsf{P}(M\cap\{\tau=t_0\}) \\
   &\qquad=\mathsf{P}((B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})\in A)\sum_{t_0\in V}\mathsf{P}(M\cap\{\tau=t_0\}) \\
   &\qquad=\mathsf{P}((B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})\in A)\mathsf{P}(M).
   \end{align}
4. Taking $M=\Omega$ and using the equality between the first and the third terms,
   \begin{align}
   \mathsf{P}((B_{t_1}^{*},\ldots,B_{t_k}^{*})\in A)&=\mathsf{P}(\{(B_{t_1}^{*},\ldots,B_{t_k}^{*})\in A\}\cap \Omega) \\
   &=\mathsf{P}((B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})\in A).
   \end{align}

Comment: 1. Okay so each member of the union is a measurable set of $\Omega \times T$? 2. I'm still a little confused about this. Lets pick two elements $a$ and $b$ in $V$. Then we will have $B^*_{t_i}=B_{t_i+a} - B_{a}$. Also there's another $b$: $B'^*_{t_i}=B_{t_i+b} - B_{b}$. Are the $t_i$'s chosen in $B^*$ are different from $B'^*$? 3. This calculation is much clearer to me except for second to last line - I have a question but it depends on the answer 2. 4. Ah - okay I see what's happening.

Comment: 1. If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ is the underlying prob. space, then $\{\tau=t_0\}\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\{B_t'\in A\}\in \mathcal{F}$ and so $\{\tau=t_0\}\cap\{B_t'\in A\}\in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: 2. Look at these [notes](https://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/MathematicalFinance/Lessons/BrownianMotion/Transformations/transformations.pdf)

Comment: okay, BM is translation invariant. 3. So for the calculation, in the second to last line the term $\mathsf{P}((B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})\in A)$ pulls out because of translation invariance then right? Technically, for each $t_0 \in V$, $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})$ represent different time points

Comment: $(B_{t_1}',\ldots,B_{t_k}')$ and $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_k})$ have the same distribution and the latter does not depend on $t_0$.